# Accumatica API problems

Tags: node.js, erp

I am making a call to Accumatica. The call works fine with Postman and was working fine with javascript until just a few days ago. I haven't changed any of the calls the error message just keeps popping up. Sometimes it does work though.

[image: image1]

I was trying to call the POs with the API call.

I am logging in with a normal username and password and not using token authentication.

Comment: It seems like the issue is on the accumatica's side. You should talk to the support.